# xpath works in google chrome extension but not in lxml

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to read the title of some table I'm scrapping with lxml. I am using the XPath Helper extension from Google Chrome to validate my xpath, which in this case is:

```
r"//tr/td[text()="+UNIQUE_ID+r"]/../../../../../b/following-sibling::text()"
```

and it works. However, in the python code, the `tree.xpath("PATTERN_ABOVE")` returns an empty list.I think that is odd that in the extension the path works, but in the python code doesn't. I think it is also awkward that the  extension normally highlight the matching cases, but not in my example. The other fields of the table am scrapping works just fine

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: remove some constraints and add them as you have it working. For example, what does this pull up from python `r"//tr/td[text()="+UNIQUE_ID+r"]` ? and what do you mean by "I think it is also awkward that the extension normally highlight the matching cases, but not in my example"

Comment: Is it possible that this xpath expression is valid yet does not match anything? One thing I would say is that your xpath expression looks as if it might be unnecessarily complicated, which would make it more difficult to debug. For one thing, unless the `td` elements you're trying to identify might also appear under `th` elements the `tr` at the beginning is redundant. If you could give us the url we might be able to suggest shorter alternatives.

Comment: I used the @salparadise debug idea and I find out that I needed to go one more time up (/../../../../../../). Six times instead of five. Now it works! Now, why it works in the extension with 5 and in python with 6 I have no ideia